# Change a value in a json file using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to change values of a json file by using javascript.
Here is the json file :

```
{ 
  "login": "",
  "password": "",
  "ip": "",
  "port": "", 
  "protocol": ""
}
```

And here is what I've tried to change the values :

```
$('#save').click(function () {
    var login = $("#login").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var ip = $("#ip").val();
    var port = $("#port").val();
    var protocol = $("#protocol").val();
    var jurl = "setting.json";

    $.getJSON(jurl,
    {
        format: "json"
    },
    function (data) {
        data.login = login;
        data.password = password;
        data.ip = ip;
        data.port = port;
        data.protocol = protocol;
    }); 
 });
```

I use `<input type="text">` to define the values

Comment: JavaScript can not save a file. What you can do is send the data to the server and have a service/script that saves it for you.

Comment: What's the real question here? Saving a file or editing the json file? If you want to find a way to edit the json file (properties), you can load the json, transform it into a javascript object and iterate through all properties to display some sort of input for every property.

Comment: the fact is that i want to edit it and save it :/

Comment: @Halcyon Isn't it what `HTTP` `PUT` method is designed for?

Comment: @Tresdin you may be right about that but I don't think modern webservers implement `PUT` that way. It's really bad for security to accept any file.

Answer (score 3):

**hi** for change values 
this is a little example

```
    var jsonObj = [{'Id':'1','Username':'Ray','FatherName':'Thompson'},  
                  {'Id':'2','Username':'Steve','FatherName':'Johnson'},
                   {'Id':'3','Username':'Albert','FatherName':'Einstein'}]

for (var i=0; i<jsonObj.length; i++) 
{
      if (jsonObj[i].Id == 3) {
        jsonObj[i].Username = "Thomas";
        break;
      }
}
```

Here's the same thing wrapped in a function:

```
function setUsername(id, newUsername) {
  for (var i=0; i<jsonObj.length; i++) {
    if (jsonObj[i].Id === id) {
      jsonObj[i].Username = newUsername;
      return;
    }
  }
}

// Call as
setUsername(3, "Thomas");
```

[check here the example](http://jsfiddle.net/cAyRs/1/)

**good luck and try ...!!!**